# Do I risk being expelled from the country?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, resident-permit, overstay

I am Cameroonian and I arrived in the United Kingdom 3 years ago as a student. I could not pay my tuition (payer ma scolarité) and my visa was canceled. One year ago I had a child with an English citizen. I asked for permanent residence. Yesterday, I received an answer and I was asked to go to a police station to indicate my presence.

Does this response mean that my request has been refused?

Can I be arrested when I am at the police station? Previously, I was arrested in a police station when asked to appear there.

Comment: Generally, if you are asked to go to a police station to indicate your presence, and nothing else, it means exactly that. Of course, if they wanted to arrest you, going to a police station will make the government's job easier, but not going wouldn't help you in the long term.

Comment: Maybe they want to know (and be sure) whether you're actually in the UK right now or not, and they may use that information to support your application.